# Compound verb in Japanese; verb(te form)+verb vs verb(masu stem form)+verb

Tags: verbs, compound-verbs

I have seen two type of compound verbs in Japanese, in one type the first verb is used in its "te form", in the second type the first verb is used in the "masu stem form". What difference does the form make of the first verb make to the meaning of the compound verb?

例：　持ってくる, this is where we have the first verb in "te form"
例：　吸い取る, this is where we have first verb in "masu stem form"

For example, why don't we say 吸って取る instead?

Answer (score 6):

Japanese tends to separate the type of compound verbs into how they behave physically.
E.g. 持ってくる is more like 2 separate action, Pick it up and bring it. However 吸い取る is more like a single action. 
E.g. 
Another one 溶け込む as a single action would never be read as 溶かして込む。
Many of these just need to be memorized.